# Is it possible to scale axis ticks in `geom_bar`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

We have this code to create a bar plot

```
x <- 1:10
z1 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "n", "n")
z2 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "p", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n")
z3 <- c("m", "m", "m", "m", "p", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n")
df <- data.frame(x, z1, z2, z3)

colors <- c("m" = "#f8766d", "n" = "#00BA38", "p" = "#619CFF")

df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Count")
```

The output is
[image]

Although the values on the y-axis are ranging from 0 to 10, I was wondering, is it possible to change them so they range from 0 to 1 with steps of say length 0.25?

Comment: There is documentation regarding this question in scales package and ggplot2: https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_number.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position = "fill"` or `position = position_fill()` will rescale each group's data to a range from 0 to 1. `scale_y_continuous` can receive specific breaks of your choice.

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1, 0.25)) +
  # scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(0.25)) +   # alternative
  xlab("") + ylab("Count")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a general way to scale from 0 to another number other than 1 and set the step length?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do. 1) Count and scale prior to ggplot2 however you like,  2) `geom_bar(aes(y = ..count../10)) +` to scale your counts down by 10 or whatever constant you like,  3) fudge the labels and make them display as 1/10th (or whatever amt) their underlying value, etc etc. It's not clear to me what general class of situations you want to address. In this case you are using `geom_bar`, which is typically used to count observations, and you want to display the result as something else, in this case 1/10th for all the values, but many other transformations could be done.